# How to parse the xml from Http Response Android

Tags: android, xml, httpresponse, saxparser

I have got the xml from the Http Response,
can any one give me an example for how to parse that http response using the sax parser in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example assumes that all data is in the root node

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();           
try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL("http://yourURLhere.com" );

        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource( url.openStream()));

        Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();

        try{
            //get the different xml fields here
            Date xmlDateLastNotification = new Date(rootElement.getAttribute("dateLastNotification").toString());
            String someOtherVariable = rootElement.getAttribute("xmlNode").toString();

        }catch(Exception e){}


    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to parse the response?  Please let us know if you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a very little library (it is two files): minimize-xml-parser. There is a tutorial on how to use it here:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/robust-xml-parsing-t4281.html

And the library is here: http://code.google.com/p/minimize-xml-parser/

Answer (score 0):

Simplified source code for parsing and working with XML data and web services in Android
[link](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/19/android-simplified-source-code-for-parsing-and-working-with-xml-data-and-web-services-in-android/)